# Is the $\alpha$-curve a topological submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Consider the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\mathcal{M}=\{ \ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ y^2=x^2(x+1)\ \}$. I'm supposed to decide whether or not $\mathcal{M}$ is a topological submanifold (TS) of $\mathbb{R}^2$. It looks like this:

[image: graph of $\mathcal{M}$]

If it's a TS, then it would have to be 1-dimensional. Here is the definition I am using:

$\mathcal{M}$ is a TS of $\mathbb{R}^2$ if for every point $p \in \mathcal{M}$ there exists an open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with $p \in V$, an open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ and a homeomorphism $\psi:U \to V$.

I don't think its a manifold. I think that a problem occurs at the origin since the curve crosses over itself there. I believe that a good homeomorphism cannot exist at the origin for this reason. How would I prove this?

I thought about using a proof by contradiction, saying suppose that there does exist a homeomorphism $\psi$ mapping an open ball $V=B_{\epsilon}(0,0)$ to some open interval $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $\psi(0,0,0)$ would be well-defined, but maybe not $\psi^{-1}(0,0,0)$? I'm not sure.

I am new to differential geometry, can someone give me a hint on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ be a sufficiently small open neighbourhood of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $U\cap \mathcal{M}$ is a neighbourhood of $(0, 0)$ in $\mathcal{M}$. It looks something like this

$\hspace{77mm}$[image]

where now I have coloured the axes red to distinguish them from the set $U\cap \mathcal{M}$ (which is still coloured black).

How many connected components does $(U\cap \mathcal{M})\setminus\{(0, 0)\}$ have? If $\mathcal{M}$ were a topological manifold $U\cap \mathcal{M}$ would be homeomorphic to an open interval $I$. How many connected components does $I$ have if a point is removed?

Comment: Okay so $U \cap \mathcal{M} \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ has 4 connected components over all, meanwhile if $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $U \cap \mathcal{M}$, then $I  \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ would have 2 connected components. Homeomorphisms map connected regions to connected regions, so we have a contradiction. Thanks!

Comment: Right idea, but what you've written is not correct. Note that $(0, 0) \not\in I$. If $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval and $f : U\cap\mathcal{M} \to I$ is a homeomorphism, then $f : (U\cap\mathcal{M})\setminus\{(0, 0)\} \to I\setminus\{f(0, 0)\}$ is also a homeomorphism. This is impossible as $(U\cap\mathcal{M})\setminus\{(0, 0)\}$ has four connected components, while $I\setminus\{f(0, 0)\}$ has two.